# how to change dir="ltr" to rtl in html tag or ion-app tag in index.html ionic2?

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, ionic2

i'm changing the direction like this

```
  <ion-nav [dir]="isRtl? 'rtl':'ltr'"></ion-nav>
```

it works fine except the menu. 
but my question now is for the `<ion-select>`
because it still in **ltr** direction because it's not under `<ion-nav>` , it's under `<ion-app>` or `<body>` or `<html>` tag.
so how can i access the variables in app.component to change the direction in index.html depending on language chosen. Or if there any other methods.

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is bind a CSS file to my component (with the decorator), and in it do

```
* {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

When you compile it, angular with add a property to all your tags, such as `ng_3590F`, and in your CSS too. This means, all your tags/IDs/classes in your component will have the right direction.

If I'm not clear, feel free to say it !

**EDIT**

To use your service in HTML, in your constructor do

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
```

And in the HTML of your component you can do

```
<your-tag [direction]="myService.myProperty"></your-tag>
```

Comment: but i need it sometimes to be ltr and sometime ltr, i mean the user may choose english os if put a star * all the app will be rtl direction

Comment: No, that's the point of using a style sheet binded to your component : the styles are only applied to your component ! so if you put the * in `ion-nav.component.scss`, it will only be applied to `ion-nav.component.html`

Comment: but the <ion-select> >> alert isn't under ion-nav . it's under <ion-app> or <body> or <html> tags

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't get it. There's several solutions, you can use a service, a global value in your environment files, the local storage ... then in your components, just do `<ion-xxx [direction]="yourService.direction"></ion-xxx>` (for a service example)

Comment: you can't access service in your html file, then your index.html doesn't have a class to import the service

Comment: Yes you can access your service in your html file, using the same name you used in your constructor. You also can give your component a property that holds the direction, that you set at ngOnInit. There is several ways to do that, as I said.

Comment: where should you declare or import your service ? in app.module and app.component ? or how ?

Comment: i know what u wrote above, but i mean specifically for index.html which is the root file in ionic2 and i think he don't have a component class where to import the service. got me ?

Answer (score 0):

when change the language (like listener  translate.onLangChange)
write this

```
this.platform.setDir('rtl',true);
```

it change the dir to rtl in html tag
and you can avoid using dir attribute in all ur app except the menu still have issue need to fix it (ionic team working on it).